# Atualizando data e relógio

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Estou criando um relógio a partir de um valor informado, o problema é que o relógio não esta sendo atualizado.

O outro problema é que na exibição  fica invertido, o mês esta vindo primeiro que o dia.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Esse valor "Hoje"e exibido corretamente e vem do servidor, não posso pegar o valor do cliente por causa do risco de alteração da data do computador.

```
function relogio() {

    var valor = document.getElementById('Hoje').value;

    var data = new Date(valor);

    var dia = data.getDate();
    var mes = data.getMonth() + 1;
    var ano = data.getFullYear();


    var horas = data.getHours();
    var minutos = data.getMinutes();
    var segundos = data.getSeconds();


    if (dia < 10) {
        dia = "0" + dia;
    }
    if (mes < 10) {
        mes = "0" + mes;
    }
    if (horas < 10) {
        horas = "0" + horas;
    }
    if (minutos < 10) {
        minutos = "0" + minutos;
    }
    if (segundos < 10) {
        segundos = "0" + segundos;
    }

    var dataAtualizada = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano + ' ' + horas + ':' + minutos + ':' + segundos;

    document.getElementById('relogio').innerHTML = dataAtualizada;
}

window.setInterval(relogio(), 1000);
```

Comment: tente fazer assim: `window.setInterval(relogio, 1000);`

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo dessa forma, se não passar o valor da certo. Mas se passar não da.

Comment: ... Não entendi. Quando você usa o setInterval, deve passar o nome da função, ou declarar ela dentro do setInterval. Se você usa o `()` dentro da função, ele não vai executar a função a cada 1 segundo, vai executar na hora que ele ler a linha e depois vai dar erro a cada 1 segundo.

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo Entendi, mas o problema esta aqui. `var data = new Date(valor);`, quando não passo esse valor, do modo que vc falou sem () atualiza, quando passo o valor ele não atualiza, só exibe e não mostra nenhum erro.

Comment: Só para entendimento, qual é o valor que está na variável `valor`? Sei que está pegando do elemento, mas o que tem no elemento "hoje"? a data de hoje? se for o caso, você pode simplesmente fazer `new Date()` que ele pega o dia/hora atual do navegador.

Comment: Ele não atualiza por que você passa uma data fixa pro objeto de data, e não "aumenta" ela. Então a data/hora que você passou vai ser atualizada todas as vezes sem aumentar. Se você não passa nenhum valor no objeto, o `new Date()` vai vir com a hora do navegador e sempre que atualizar ele vai pegar a hora do navegador em que a função rodou, ao invés de um valor fixo que não muda.

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo, A variável está pegando a Data atual do servidor no seguinte `formato 07/12/2018 10:37:06`, eu não posso pegar como  `new Date ` por nesse caso eu pego da maquina do usuário e ele pode troca o horário e não bater com servidor .

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86757/discussion-between-mattheus-spoo-and-mba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, segue o código.

```js
document.getElementById('relogio').value = document.getElementById('Hoje').value

function relogio() {
    var valor = document.getElementById('relogio').value.split(' '); //divide dia/horário
    var dia = valor[0].split('/').reverse().join('-'); //converte a data em formato americano
    valor = dia + ' ' + valor[1]; //une a data americana com o horário
    var data = new Date(valor); // cria o objeto de data
    var atualizado = data.setSeconds(data.getSeconds() + 1) // adiciona um segundo
    atualizado = new Date(atualizado) //cria a data atualizada
    document.getElementById('relogio').value = atualizado.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', {hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'}); //atualiza a data já editada pro formato solicitado
}

setInterval(relogio, 1000) //roda a cada 1 segundo.
```

```html
<input class="form-control input-print larg" type="text" id="Hoje" style="display:none" value='12/07/2018 11:30:00'/>
<input class="form-control input-print" id="relogio" type="text" readonly>
```

Seu principal erro foi receber a hora de uma string, mas não aumentar um segundo nela. Se você recebe o horário do servidor e coloca dentro de uma tag html dentro da página, precisa garantir que ela vai ser atualizada pelo servidor, ou pelo javascript. Como o servidor não atualiza, editamos a string para colocar num objeto de data, adicionamos um segundo no valor dela, e retornamos a string pro valor original. Vou deixar alguns links para que possa estudar e entender o que foi feito, mas creio que com os comentários dá pra ter uma noção.

Só quero deixar claro que o relógio vai atualizar no front end, então se a hora do servidor for modificada a pagina precisa ser recarregada.

Links úteis:

[.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

[Objeto Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Obrigado Máttheus, funcionou perfeitamente. Parabéns.